# Values of coefficient of expansion differ,when temperatures are measured on centigrade scale and on Fahrenheit scale separately

Tags: temperature, unit-conversion

In solving above question, it was given that

> Change of $5 ℃ = $ change of $9 ℉$

I only know the relation that $$\dfrac{C}{5}=\dfrac{F - 32}{9}$$

I don't know how Change of $5 ℃ = $ change of $9 ℉$ . So how can we say that?

Comment: You have shown no attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For different scales of measurement, the following equation always remains a constant for a given meaning of $T_{lower}$ and $T_{upper}$:

$$\frac{T_X - T_{lower}}{T_{upper} - T_{lower}} = constant \tag{1}$$

The equation gives a constant value because we assume that the scales relate the temperature to a given state linearly. The slope does not change. Doubling the property (temperature) will double the value of the temperature measured by the scale.

It is important to understand the meaning of "for a given meaning of $T_{lower}$ and $T_{upper}$". You choose two temperatures qualitatively. For example, the boiling point of alcohol and the melting point of ice. You then substitute the value of $T_{lower}$ and $T_{upper}$ in the selected scale. The following example will clear things up.

We generally use the boiling and melting points of water for $T_{upper}$ and $T_{lower}$ respectively.

On the celsius scale, water boils at $100$ and solidifies at $0$. Plugging in these numbers in equation $(1)$, you get

$$\frac{T_C - 0}{100 - 0} = \frac{T_C}{100} = constant \tag{2}$$

On the Fahrenheit scale, water boils at $212$ and solidifies at $32$. Plugging in these numbers in equation $(1)$, you get

$$\frac{T_F - 32}{212 - 32} = \frac{T_F - 32}{180} = constant \tag{3}$$

Equating $(2)$ and $(3)$ together, you get

$$\frac{T_C}{100} = \frac{T_F - 32}{180}$$

$$\frac{T_C}{5} = \frac{T_F - 32}{9} \tag{4}$$

The equation $(4)$ can be rewritten as
$$T_C = \frac{5}{9}T_F - \frac{160}{9} \tag{5}$$

Equation $(5)$ can be compared with the general form of equation of a line:

$$y = mx + c$$

The slope in equation $(5)$ is equal to $\frac{5}{9}$. The slope measures the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$. In our case, it tells by how much $T_C$ increases for a unit increase in $T_F$.

$$slope = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{\Delta T_C}{\Delta T_F} =\frac{5}{9}$$

$$\Delta T_C = \frac{5}{9}\Delta T_F $$

If you increase $T_C$ by 5, you get

$$\frac{5}{9}\Delta T_F = 5$$

$$\Delta T_F = 9$$

Therefore, by increasing $T_C$ by 5, $T_F$ will increase by 9.